# How to solve the Query using JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I had two tables namely students and pass. In both tables, one column is common i.e. ID. I need the students data including pass table details in only one horizontal row, now it's showing in three different rows. Students data is keep going redundant.

students

```
ID   Name Age
1     XYZ    25
2     ABC    15
```

pass

```
ID    subject      External  Internal
1       English       20       22
1       Maths         25       15
1       Science       50       25
2       history       15       14
2       Geography     14       21
```

Expected Output:

```
ID   NAME   AGE                         Pass 
1    XYZ    25      English       20       22  Maths         25       15  Science       50       25
2    ABC    15      history       15       14  Geography     14       21
```

Actual Output:

```
ID  NAME  AGE  SUBJECT      EXTERNAL INTERNAL
1   XYZ    25   English        20       22
1   XYZ    25    Maths         25       15
1   XYZ    25    Science       50       25
```

SQL QUERY:

```
SELECT * FROM students LEFT JOIN pass ON students.ID=pass.ID order by students.ID
```

Is is possible to show in one horizontal row? I tried Join, but I think it's not working.

Comment: Join will not work.. You will have to use aggregate function.. In oracle I used LISTAGG.. For oracle I used like this.. http://tech.pranavmaniar.in/oracle-aggregate-string-into-csv/  ... For mysql similar things should also exist

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but you have the results in 1 column.

```
SELECT
  s.*,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(p.subject,' : ',p.External,' : ',p.Internal) SEPARATOR '  --  ')
FROM students s
LEFT JOIN pass p ON s.ID=p.ID
GROUP BY p.ID
ORDER BY s.ID;
```

Comment: Its not what he asked for

Answer (score 0):

an ugly solution:

```
SELECT ID,NAME,
group_concat(concat(SUBJECT,"==ex=>",EXTERNAL,"==IN=>",INTERNAL,"==|"), SEPARATOR "--|") 
FROM students LEFT JOIN pass ON students.ID=pass.ID 
group by ID,NAME order by students.ID
```

Comment: Its not what he asked for either

Answer (score 0):

try it-

```
SELECT st.ID, st.name, st.age,  
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(ps.subject),',',1) AS subject_1, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(ps.external),',',1) AS external_1, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(ps.interval),',',1) AS interval_1, 
IF((LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(ps.subject)) - LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(ps.subject SEPARATOR ''))) < 1,'',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(ps.subject),',',2),',',-1)) AS subject_2, 
IF((LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(ps.external)) - LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(ps.external SEPARATOR ''))) < 1,'',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(ps.external),',',2),',',-1)) AS external_2, 
 IF((LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(ps.interval)) - LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(ps.interval SEPARATOR ''))) < 1,'',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(ps.interval),',',2),',',-1)) AS interval_2, 
IF((LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(ps.subject)) - LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(ps.subject ''))) < 2,'',SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(ps.subject),',',-1)) AS subject_3 
IF((LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(ps.external)) - LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(ps.external ''))) < 2,'',SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(ps.external),',',-1)) AS external_3 
IF((LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(ps.interval)) - LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(ps.interval ''))) < 2,'',SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(ps.interval),',',-1)) AS interval_3 
FROM students AS st 
LEFT JOIN pass AS ps ON st.ID=ps.ID 
GROUP BY students.ID;
```

Comment: As I did not execute this query, so let me know if you get any issue so that I can correct it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use dynamic pivoting to solve your problem. One approach could be to use this statements:

```
SELECT      GROUP_CONCAT(tmp.x)
    FROM    (
        SELECT      CONCAT('MAX(IF(p.subject = ''', p.subject, ''', p.External, NULL)) ', p.subject, '_External, MAX(IF(p.subject = ''', p.subject, ''', p.Internal, NULL)) ', p.subject, '_Internal') x
            FROM    pass p
        GROUP BY    p.subject
        ) tmp
    INTO    @query;

SELECT      CONCAT('SELECT s.*, ', @query, ' FROM students s JOIN pass p ON p.ID = s.ID GROUP BY p.ID')
    INTO    @sql;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```